# saltstack add customized service to centos7,After executing cmd.run "systemctl daemon-reload", service.running still prompts service is not available

Tags: centos7, salt-stack, systemctl

when I use saltstack(ver:2018.3.1 (Oxygen)) to deploy Customized Services,sls:

```
#salt command line: salt 'SaltStack-01' state.sls devops.installService pillar='{"name": "cmdb-agent"}'

#If the service is already installed and running, stop it first
stopService:
  service.dead:
    - name: {{ pillar['name'] }}
    #- require:
    #  - service: {{ pillar['name'] }}


#copy  executable files
agent:
  file.managed:
    - name: /usr/sbin/{{ pillar['name'] }}
    - source: salt://devops/installServiceFile/{{ pillar['name'] }}
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 744

#systemd reload for centos7
systemd-reload:
  #module.run:
  #  - name: service.systemctl_reload
  cmd.run:
    - name: systemctl --system daemon-reload && systemctl status cmdb-agent

#install service
installService:
  file.managed:
  {% if grains['osmajorrelease'] == 7 %}
    - name: /usr/lib/systemd/system/{{ pillar['name'] }}.service
    - source: salt://devops/installServiceFile/{{ pillar['name'] }}_Centos7.service
    - onchanges_in:
       - cmd: systemd-reload
  {% else %}
    - name: /etc/init.d/{{ pillar['name'] }}
    - source: salt://devops/installServiceFile/{{ pillar['name'] }}_Centos6.service
  {% endif %}
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 755

#Start service and set the service to start on boot
startService:
  service.running:
    - name: {{ pillar['name'] }}
    - enable: True
```

**cmd.run "systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl status cmdb-agent" can take effect, "systemctl status cmdb-agent" can display service status but service.runging will prompts "service xxxx is not available",like this**

[root@xxx] salt-call -l debug  state.sls devops.installService pillar='{"name": "cmdb-agent"}'

```
local:
----------
          ID: stopService
    Function: service.dead
        Name: cmdb-agent
      Result: True
     Comment: The named service cmdb-agent is not available
     Started: 17:16:53.491952
    Duration: 95.617 ms
     Changes:
----------
          ID: agent
    Function: file.managed
        Name: /usr/sbin/cmdb-agent
      Result: True
     Comment: File /usr/sbin/cmdb-agent is in the correct state
     Started: 17:16:53.594176
    Duration: 505.695 ms
     Changes:
----------
          ID: installService
    Function: file.managed
        Name: /usr/lib/systemd/system/cmdb-agent.service
      Result: True
     Comment: File /usr/lib/systemd/system/cmdb-agent.service updated
     Started: 17:16:54.102273
    Duration: 80.155 ms
     Changes:
              ----------
              diff:
                  New file
              mode:
                  0755
----------
          ID: systemd-reload
    Function: cmd.run
        Name: systemctl --system daemon-reload && systemctl status cmdb-agent
      Result: False
     Comment: Command "systemctl --system daemon-reload && systemctl status cmdb-agent" run
     Started: 17:16:54.183318
    Duration: 156.69 ms
     Changes:
              ----------
              pid:
                  179954
              retcode:
                  3
              stderr:
              stdout:
                  * cmdb-agent.service - CMDB agent
                     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/cmdb-agent.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
                     Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2021-07-29 15:55:03 CST; 1h 21min ago
                   Main PID: 173362 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

                  Jul 29 15:54:32 SHMGMT009025105 systemd[1]: Started CMDB agent.
                  Jul 29 15:55:03 SHMGMT009025105 systemd[1]: Stopping CMDB agent...
                  Jul 29 15:55:03 SHMGMT009025105 systemd[1]: Stopped CMDB agent.
----------
          ID: startService
    Function: service.running
        Name: cmdb-agent
      Result: False
     Comment: The named service cmdb-agent is not available
     Started: 17:16:54.340724
    Duration: 1.703 ms
     Changes:

Summary for local
------------
Succeeded: 3 (changed=2)
Failed:    2
------------
Total states run:     5
Total run time: 839.860 ms
```

Comment: The return code of `reload && status` of service is not 0 (`retcode: 3`), so it could be that it didn't actually work. What happens when you use `service.systemctl_reload` module?

Comment: The return code is 3 because the status command shows that the service is not running, so the return code is 3. I removed the status command and the reload return code is 0. But service.running still reports an error.